# Google Maps Distance Matrix Api with multiple values in iOS application

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

I'm using Google Distance Matrix Api in my application to get distance and time between two points:

```
NSString *link              = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=55.9667,25.5833&destinations=54.6833,25.2833&mode=drive&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];
NSURL *url                  = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:link];
NSURLRequest *request       = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

Everything works fine, but when I want to get distances and times between multiple points with URL:

```
NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=55.9667,25.5833|55.5000,25.6000&destinations=54.6833,25.2833|55.7000,21.1306&mode=drive&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-ts"];
```

I get an error:

```
@"NSLocalizedDescription" : @"unsupported URL"
@"NSUnderlyingError" : domain: @"kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork" - code: 18446744073709550614
```

And if I put this URL in browser it gets me what I want. Is multiple origins/destinations is unavailable in iOS? Or am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE:** 
It doesn't convert my link to NSURL. It is nil.

Comment: You're supposed to get an error response from the Google API (e.g: Invalid Key). Can you post what is the error that you get so that we can help debug?

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the non-ASCII characters in your link.

```
NSString* escapedLink = [link stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Nice, I remember I had this problem like 3 years ago but couldn't remember :) nice find